# How to Create an Alert Processing Rule using the Azure Monitor - Java SDK

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-monitoring, azure-sdk-for-java, azure-java-tools

I'm trying to create an Alert Processing Rule using the Azure Monitor SDK in Java, but I'm having trouble finding the right approach. **I want to programmatically create an Alert Processing Rule**
**I have already set up the Azure Management SDK in my Java project and have authentication working using the Azure Active Directory credentials.** However, I couldn't find a direct method or class for creating Alert Processing Rules in the SDK.

I have already checked the Microsoft documentation, but I couldn't find specific details or code examples for this scenarios.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/alerts-processing-rules?tabs=portal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Create an Alert Processing Rule using the Azure Monitor - Java SDK

You can use the below code to create an alert processing rule using the Azure Monitor java-SDK.

**Code:**

```
import com.azure.resourcemanager.alertsmanagement.models.AddActionGroups;
import com.azure.resourcemanager.alertsmanagement.models.AlertProcessingRule;
import com.azure.resourcemanager.alertsmanagement.models.AlertProcessingRuleProperties;
import com.azure.core.credential.TokenCredential;
import com.azure.core.management.AzureEnvironment;
import com.azure.identity.DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder;
import com.azure.core.management.profile.AzureProfile;
import com.azure.resourcemanager.alertsmanagement.AlertsManagementManager;

import java.util.Arrays;


public final class App {

    public static boolean runSample(com.azure.resourcemanager.alertsmanagement.AlertsManagementManager azureResourceManager) {

            AlertProcessingRule ma = azureResourceManager
                    .alertProcessingRules()
                    .define("AddActionGroupsBySeverity")
                    .withRegion("Global")
                    .withExistingResourceGroup("v-venkat-mindtree")
                    .withProperties(
                new AlertProcessingRuleProperties()
                    .withScopes(Arrays.asList("/subscriptions/xxxx/resourceGroups/xxxx/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/vm678"))
                    .withActions(
                        Arrays
                            .asList(
                                new AddActionGroups()
                                    .withActionGroupIds(
                                        Arrays
                                            .asList(
                                                "/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/microsoft.insights/actiongroups/actiongrp326"))))
                    .withDescription("Add ActionGroup1 to all alerts in the subscription")
                    .withEnabled(true))
            .create();
            return true;
        }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            final AzureProfile profile = new AzureProfile("<YOUR_TENANT_ID>", "<YOUR_SUBSCRIPTION_ID>", AzureEnvironment.AZURE);
            final TokenCredential credential = new DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder()
                .authorityHost(profile.getEnvironment().getActiveDirectoryEndpoint())
                .build();

            AlertsManagementManager azureResourceManager = AlertsManagementManager
                .authenticate(credential, profile);

           System.out.println("Alert Processing rule is created.....");

            runSample(azureResourceManager);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Alert Processing rule is created.....
```

[image]

**Portal:**

[image]

**Reference:**

[Azure-sdk-for-java/sdk/alertsmanagement· GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/azure-resourcemanager-alertsmanagement_1.0.0-beta.1/sdk/alertsmanagement/azure-resourcemanager-alertsmanagement/SAMPLE.md#alertprocessingrules_createorupdate)